# system nullreferenceexception on recordset

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

Before I asked this question I looked into all the suggest made by SO and took a look into this to (What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?)

I have an function in my Usercontrol

User control:

```
Function MedewerkerNaam(Medewerker as integer, Meisjesnaam as boolean) 
    MedewerkerNaam = "Onbekend"
    If IIsNumeric(Medewerker) = True Then
        rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        rs.open ("SELECT Medewerkers.Medewerkers_Voornaams_AchternaamVoorvoegsel, Medewerkers.Medewerkers_Achternaam, Medewerkers.Medewerkers_MeisjesnaamVoorvoegsel, Medewerkers.Medewerkers_Meisjesnaam FROM Medewerkers WHERE Medewerkers.Medewerkers_ID = 0" & int(Medewerker), strCon)
        If NOT rs.EOF Then
            MedewerkerNaam = rs("Medewerkers_Voornaam") & " " & rs("Medewerkers_AchternaamVoorvoegsel") & " " & rs("Medewerkers_Achternaam")
            If Meisjesnaam = True AND rs("Medewerkers_Meisjesnaam") <> "" Then MedewerkerNaam = MedewerkerNaam & " - " & rs("Medewerkers_MeisjesnaamVoorvoegsel") & " " & rs("Medewerkers_Meisjesnaam")
        End If
        rs.Close
         rs = nothing
    End If
End Function
```

In my webform.aspx:

```
 <%dim deneme as new basic%>

 this is a testttt : <%=deneme.MedewerkerNaam(10,false)%>
```

Why do I get the error:

```
system.nullreferenceexception object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

The line where the error comes from:

```
 rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
```

Sorry if it's something stupid it's just that I don't get it And how can I make sure I won't get this problem again ?

Comment: Where have you initialised Server?

Comment: at the web.config @ProGrammer and I tested the script in aspx it works but when I put this script in a function and call it from ascx file it gives me an error

Comment: You copied and pasted your question to create a new one. When you did you forgot to copy the link to the question _What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?_ I would check `Server` is actually initialised by _debugging_ your code and if it isn't, look into _why_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple scope issue. **Server** is a property of *System.Web.UI.Page* which your aspx is inheriting from. I am guessing your function **MedewerkerNaam**  is defined outside of this aspx page class, so therefore the  Server property is not visible.

You have two options:

1. Move your function **MedewerkerNaam** to reside inside of the aspx class that inherits from *System.Web.UI.Page*.

   Your code should then work since the base aspx page class' *Server*
   property will be visible, or
2. Pass the Server object into your function like so...

   ```
   Function MedewerkerNaam(Medewerker as integer, Meisjesnaam as boolean, Server As System.Web.HttpServerUtility) 
       ...
   End Function
   ```

and when you call MedewerkerNaam from your aspx class add include the Server property like so:

```
Public Class your_aspx_class
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Sub your_method(...)
        ...
        something = MedewerkerNaam(someint, somebool, Server)
        ...
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: If it were a scope issue, there would be a compile error saying that `Server` did not exist.

Comment: I have A file with 200 functions + is there a way to do this without touching the functions ? Or do i have to add it manualy 1 by 1

Comment: @Chris Dunaway I am guessing Option Explicit is probably not specified in the project. Option Explicit and Option Strict are always good to specify!

Comment: Profa - one way to do this would be to force option 1 by renaming your class that contains all of your functions to the same name as your ASPX class using the 'Partial' keyword, ie

Public Class MyExternalFunctionsClass
   Public Function MedewerkerNaam(...)
   ...etc....
End Class

...becomes...

Partial Public Class your_aspx_class
   Public Function MedewerkerNaam(...)
   ...etc....
End Class

...where 'your_aspx_class' in my example is replaced with the name of your aspx class that inherits from System.Web.UI.Page in your web project.

Comment: Another option would be to create a property called 'Server' (as type System.Web.HttpServerUtility) in the class that contains all of your functions and initialize it once with the value from the ASPX page's Server property.